# Search substring in line and then replace that line in text file

Tags: python

I am trying to write script that will first make a backup of the text file, then open it and search for line with specified string/sub string and then replace that line with new string/line.

To be more precise, this would be a file with values for some system options, and i want my script to find specific option and change it's current value.

So far i have this but it will only add new value to existing one, it will not replace it. Would appreciate the help.

```
import os
import shutil

shutil.copy2('C:/file_location/values.txt', 'C:/file_location/values.txt.backup')

with open('C:/file_location/values.txt') as values: 
  updated_values = values.read().replace('SystemOption', 'SystemOption = 1')

with open('C:/file_location/values.txt', "w") as new_values:
    new_values.write(updated_values)
```

SystemOption = 0
after i run script i get:
SystemOption = 0 = 1

Desired effect after script is run is:
SystemOption = 1

So i want to change from 0 to 1.

Problem is that in file the value can be either 0 or 1, so that is why i want to change entire line to be sure that value is 1 after script.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: It work, do update the values.txt

Comment: You have `SystemOption = 0` and replace the `SystemOption` part with `SystemOption = 1`, thus ending up with `SystemOption = 1 = 0` which makes sense from a programming perspective. Since you have some variance in the input data ("Problem is that in file the value can be either 0 or 1") you should look into [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: @kalatabe Ah it makes sense now, thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) in python

```
with open('C:/file_location/values.txt') as values: 
    updated_values = values.read()
    updated_values = re.sub('SystemOption = 0', 'SystemOption = 1',updated_values)
```

Comment: Here regex just over kills, string replace shouldn't be sufficient ?

Comment: Doesn't work, it did same thing, it added value, SystemOption = 1 and when i run with your changes i get SystemOption = 1 = 1

Comment: can you provide example string? You need to change SystemOption  = 0 to SystemOption  = 1 right? Then you may need to only replace `SystemOption = 0` to `SystemOption  = 1`

Comment: Yes exactly, note, file can already have that option set to 1, so that is why i cannot search for full string and replace it.

Comment: No issue i made a typo sorry, if value is 0 it will change it to 1 so your sample works fine, thanks for help. I was just looking for a way to identify attribute (SystemOption) and no matter what value it holds at the moment, change it to desired value. But the re module as you said will be the way to go, need to dig in it.

Comment: @cuke_male you can upwote if my solution helps your question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import shutil

shutil.copy2('C:/file_location/values.txt', 'C:/file_location/values.txt.backup')

with open('C:/file_location/values.txt') as values:
    updated_values = values.read()
    if 'SystemOption' in updated_values:
        updated_values = updated_values.replace('SystemOption = 0', 'SystemOption = 1', 1)

with open('C:/file_location/values.txt', "w") as new_values:
    new_values.write(updated_values)
```

Comment: Just tried it, works fine. If value is 0 it will change it to 1 and if value is 1 it will keep the value of 1. Thanks mate.